Format page in in docx on page where specific paragraph is placed (python docx)
I need to apply below function in document on specific page.
Function purpose is to set up specific style and margins settings. I mark this page with paragraph (see screenshot).
How I can identify this page in function to apply in only on the page with marker?
I would really appreciate your help!

from docx import Document
def set_up_doc(doc, fund_name, section_index=0):
    # Apply styles to the specified section
    section = doc.sections[section_index]

    # Set paragraph spacing
    paragraph_format = doc.styles['Normal'].paragraph_format
    paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0.1)

    # Set font name and size
    style = doc.styles['Normal']
    font = style.font
    font.name = 'Arial'
    font.size = Pt(9)

    # Set up margin width for the section
    section.top_margin = Cm(2.12)
    section.bottom_margin = Cm(2.01)
    section.left_margin = Cm(0.88)
    section.right_margin = Cm(1.02)


    return doc```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/XWmSgEWc.png

